# vim submatch - trying to put quotes around a string

Tags: vim, regex

I'm trying to use the vim submatch command to put quotes around all strings of characters in a line of text, and it doesnt work. Here's what I'm doing

```
:s:\a*\a:\(submatch(0)\):g
```

All it does is replace all strings with the string (submatch(0)). How do I make vim do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

submatch is not the best solution to do this. I was doing some helpgrep on `\\=`

And I find this:

```
                *sub-replace-special* *:s\=*
When the {string} starts with "\=" it is evaluated as an expression, see
|sub-replace-expression|.  You can use that for any special characters.
Otherwise these characters in {string} have a special meaning:
```

If you insist in using submatch you can use it in this way:

```
s:\a*\a:\='"'.submatch(0).'"'
```

However a more readable solution is:

```
s:\a*\a:"\0"
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to capture each match by surrounding the pattern with a pair of braces `\(` and `\)`. Having done this you can use the actual matched text in the replacement pattern with `\1`.

The following command does what you want:

```
:s:\(\a*\a\):"\1":g
```